# underscore is coming from broker for published image path

Tags: broker, binary

We have component in Tridion and images are attached to those component. We publish component and try to get image url from broker using  below method by passing image tcm id but we didn't receive image path for some of the images  instead of image path we got "_".

```
public string GetUrlForUri(string uri) 
{ 
var item = BinaryMetaFactory.GetMeta(uri); 
return item == null ? string.Empty : item.UrlPath; 

}
```

Could you please help us to find out solution of this problem?

Thanks
Vivek Chauhan

Answer (score 1):

Could you try running this query on your database server to check the url getting saved in db

```
select URL from BINARYVARIANTS where PUBLICATION_ID='<pubid>' and BINARY_ID='<itemid>'
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply
Issue got resolved , Actually CT attached to that component is not pushing binary in package. now we changes our CT and our image is got publish and got right url.